# Send data from aws api gateway to http endpoint in x-www-form-urlencoded format

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have an AWS API gateway proxy method. If I post data to AWS API gateway, then AWS API gateway posts data to my PHP backend. I have this mapping template in API gateway:

```
{
    "body-json" : $input.json('$'),
    "context" : {
        "cognito-identity-id" : "$context.identity.cognitoIdentityId"
    }
}
```

The problem is that API gateway posts data in JSON format. And PHP does not understand JSON (content type application/json), $_POST array is empty. PHP understands application/x-www-form-urlencoded format. How to make AWS API gateway to send data in x-www-form-urlencoded format?

Answer (score 0):

Silly question, but have you tried [PHP's JSON Decode function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)?

```
    $json = '{
       "body-json" : $input.json(\'$\'),
       "context" : {
        "cognito-identity-id" : "$context.identity.cognitoIdentityId"
       }
     }';

$phpArray = json_decode($json, true);
```

Which will produce an associative PHP array from that json.

Comment: No. I haven't got access to PHP backend. I want to fix it on AWS API gateway side

Comment: Your question refers to PHP not being able to parse JSON (which isn't accurate). I would edit your original question to better define your limitations. JavaScript can also be used to parse JSON such as JSON.parse(yourJSON);

Answer (score 0):

The Amazon API Gateway uses the following logic to select a mapping template:

When the Content-Type header is absent in the request, API Gateway assumes that its default value is application/json. For such a request, API Gateway uses application/json as the default key to select the mapping template, if one is defined. When no template matches this key, API Gateway passes the payload through unmapped if the passthroughBehavior property is set to WHEN_NO_MATCH or WHEN_NO_TEMPLATES.

When the Accept header is not specified in the request, API Gateway assumes that its default value is application/json. In this case, API Gateway selects an existing mapping template for application/json to map the response payload. If no template is defined for application/json, API Gateway selects the first existing template and uses it as the default to map the response payload. Similarly, API Gateway uses the first existing template when the specified Accept header value does not match any existing template key. If no template is defined, API Gateway simply passes the response payload through unmapped.

For example, suppose that an API has a application/json template defined for a request payload and has a application/xml template defined for the response payload. If the client sets the "Content-Type : application/json", and "Accept : application/xml" headers in the request, both the request and response payloads will be processed with the corresponding mapping templates. If the Accept:application/xml header is absent, the application/xml mapping template will be used to map the response payload. To return the response payload unmapped instead, you must set up an empty template for application/json.

Only the MIME type is used from the Accept and Content-Type headers when selecting a mapping template. For example, a header of "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8" will have a request template with the application/json key selected.

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/request-response-data-mappings.html#transforming-request-response-body